# The role of Dependency inversion principle on frontend development

Tags: reactjs, solid

I was learning React and came across something called "SOLID" especially Dependency inversion principle. Then after having done some research, I found these articles https://medium.com/@vittorioguerriero/dependency-inversion-in-react-58f1545dc039 and https://dmitripavlutin.com/frontend-architecture-stable-and-volatile-dependencies/. The question is Is it best practice to implement DI principle in React? Since it seemed to me that the implementation of Dependency inversion principle in react makes code more complicated.

Answer (score -1):

> The question is Is it best practice to implement DI principle in React?

The answer is definitely yes. I will even say more, DI should be implemented everywhere and always. I would suggest you read [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) book by [Uncle Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_C._Martin).

> Since it seemed to me that the implementation of Dependency inversion principle in react makes code more complicated.

I bag to differ. DI makes code less complicated, IMHO. Wanna show an example of why you think it makes code complicated?